# How to resize disk partitions only using console

Tags: partitioning, disk

I have a Oracle Cloud VPS with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS aarch64 minimal and I want to resize the partitions of my disk

Comment: None of the volumes you want to be resized can be done while they are mounted.  You will have to unmount them to resize them. This should be done through the Oracle config page and not the OS.  https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Block/Tasks/resizingavolume.htm

Comment: @Terrance thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gparted` has a command line interface.

If you don't already have it installed, run the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted
```

As far as how to use all of the features of `gparted` from the command line, review the manual:

```
man gparted
```

Note: You can not resize any partitions that are currently mounted. So you will not be able to resize the partition that contains the root file system while the system is running.